# Cannot Connect to Database Server MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, server

I'm facing a problem with MySQL on Windows 10.

It is my first time using DB and I don't know how to solve this error. I fully uninstalled and cleaned all folders and hidden folders related to MySQL and installed again, but did not work.

```
Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MySQL server at localhost:3306:

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:YES)
```

Please:

1. Check that MySQL is running on address localhost
2. Check that MySQL is reachable on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the
   default, but this can be changed)
3. Check the user root has rights to connect to localhost from your
   address (MySQL rights define what clients can connect to the server
   and from which machines)
4. Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using
   the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address
   you are connecting from

Edit: CMD error:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @mario which command or utility you are using to connect to mysql

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it using "Xampp" or "Wampp"? If not, try Xampp they work perfectly for me in Windows 10.
You can download it here: [xamppdownload](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

Also, make sure that you dont install Xamppto local disk C. Try another drive as it will prevent some issues as yours.

Comment: I just installed

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the password for root and grant privileges ? Please check that first since the error showing Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

[try this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38803/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user)

Answer (score 0):

login via this "mysql -u root" (without quotes)
And you should change your root password
Also check your log at /var/log/mysqld.log this has default password listed will save lot of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can connect with the database.

```
// Database configuration
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "Password";
    $database_name = "database name";

// Get connection object and set the charset
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database_name);
    $conn->set_charset("utf8");
```